# Dynamic icon for HandledMenuItem

Tags: java, rcp, e4

I would like to dynamically set the icon of a `HandledMenuItem` in an `RCP` `e4` application.
Basically, I am looking for a similar behaviour to the @CanExecute method of the menu item's handler.

Do you know of any way how to do this?

Comment: HandledMenuItem and @CanExecute are Eclipse e4 RCP not SWT. So is this an e4 application?

Comment: Of course, you are right.

Comment: A dynamic menu contribution might work: http://blog.vogella.com/2013/03/21/dynamic-menu-contributions-in-eclipse-e4/